# Booting Raspberry Pi for the first time!

Tags: raspbian

I have already written raspbian to the SD card successfully.But nothing happens when i insert it into the raspberry pi.Only the red light glowing.Nothing shows on the computer screen.

Answer (score 3):

Plug it in *after* inserting the SD card.

Answer (score 0):

You require to put the card in before the Pi boots, this is because the code embedded in Pi which runs on power up.

The code is unable to find the sd card after it boots, so the sd card must be in before the Pi boots.